# How can I send tokens to 0x address - burning tokens?

Tags: ethereum

I can't add the burn method to an existing token, so I have only one way send tokens to 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, but I can't transfer tokens to 0x address.

I get error Recipient address is invalid in Metamask and Remix, when trying send via contract, but I see people some how send to this address.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to

- Crete a smart contract called `Burner`
- Any tokens send to this contract would be forwarded to 0x0 by the smart contract itself
- Burner contract can also emit events that signal that token supply has been reduced and has a function `getCirculatingTokenSupply()`, so that it is easier for the users to check how many tokens are out there

Answer (score 5):

I found solution with this address

0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead